# while installing i'm getting "importError: cannot import name 'main'" error

Tags: python, pip, gcloud

while installing packages

$pip3 install flask-bcrypt

it shows
from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your code with this sample :

```
from pip import __main__
```

Then you should be able to access the main by :

```
sys.exit(__main__)
```